# Solve the following ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}x - \dfrac{dy}{dx} - x^4 = 0$

From here i tried to proceed by integrating both sides w.r.t $x$, but it seems to yield even more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}x-\frac{dy}{dx}-x^4=0$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}x+\frac{dy}{dx}-2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^4$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^4$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y\right)=x^4$$
$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=\frac{x^5}{5}+c$$

Can you continue and finish this now?

Comment: Thank you Schrondingerscat. Yes, by the intergrating factor method.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to note that if $y\propto x^5$, then $x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ are both $\propto x^4$. Trying $y=Cx^5$ leads you to $20Cx^4-5Cx^4-x^4=0$, and taking $C=\frac{1}{15}$ gives us the particular solution $y=\frac{x^5}{15}$.

Now, writing $y=\frac{x^5}{15}+u$, our equation becomes $xu''-u'=0$. We can rearrange this to $\frac{u''}{u'}=\frac{1}{x}$, and integrating this gives that $u'=Ax$, for constant $A$, and thus that $u=Ax^2+B$ (absorbing a factor of $2$ in the $x^2$ term).

Thus, our general solution is $y(x)=\frac{x^5}{15}+Ax^2+B$, for constants $A,B$.

An alternative approach is to spot that the first two terms are reminiscent of the quotient rule, and to try leverage that, viz:

$xy''-y'-x^4=0\implies\frac{xy''-y'}{x^2}-x^2=0\implies\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{x^3}{3})=0$

We thus integrate piece-by-piece:

$\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{x^3}{3}=A\implies y'=\frac{x^4}{3}+Ax\implies y=\frac{x^5}{15}+Ax^2+B$

and retrieve the first answer, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$$xy'' - y' = x^4 $$
multiply by $x$
$$x^2y'' - xy' = x^5 $$
This is [Euler-Cauchy Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)

so, the characteristic equation of homogeneous D.E  is
$$r(r-1)-r=0$$ 
$$r_0=0$$
$$r_1=2$$
$$y_c=c_1x^0+c_2x^2$$
to find the particular solution, let 
$$y_p=Ax^5$$
$$y'_p=5Ax^4$$
$$y''_p=20Ax^3$$
$$x^2(20Ax^3)-x(5Ax^4)=x^5$$
$$A=\frac{1}{15}$$
hence
$$y=c_1+c_2x^2+\frac{1}{15}x^5$$